# Not able to require a directive from another directive in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Getting an error while trying to `require` **directive** `msgpallete` from **directive** `itemCounter`.
I have removed codes from some functions which i thought is irreelevant in this context.
Do ask for any code which you think is important.Kinda new to angular. So may have many misconceptions.

**HTML** snippet

```
<msgpallete msg="message"></msgpallete>
<li ng-repeat = "item in items">

<item-counter 
    startcounter = 1 
    resetter     = 'reset' 
    name         = {{item.name}} >
    {{item.name}}
</item-counter><br><br>
</li>
```

**JS** snippet

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  ....code irreleveant in this context....
})
.directive('msgpallete',function(){
 return{
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{},
    template:"<h4>Added"+""+" "+"</h4>"
  }
})   
.directive('itemCounter',function(){
return {    
    restrict:'E',
    require:'msgpallete',
    scope:{
      resetter:"="
    },
    transclude:true,
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){
        scope.qty = attr.startcounter
        scope.add = function(){}
        scope.remove = function(){}
        scope.reset = function(){}
        scope.$watch();
    },
    template:"<a ng-transclude></a> &nbsp"+
             "<button ng-click='remove();' >less</button>"+
             "{{qty}}" +
             "<button ng-click='add();'>more</button>&nbsp"+
             "<button ng-click='reset();'>submit</button>"
}
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: As [per documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) `require` can reference only *sibling* (directive on the same element - maybe this is where the confusion comes from) or *parent*.

Comment: @YD1m:are u serious? what if my `msgpallette` is at the top of the page and `item-counter` needs to be at the bottom. Then how can i nest it like that?

Comment: @PavelHoral:will u be able to answer for my above comment

Comment: you need to put `ng-repeat ` with `li` inside `msgpallete` element then only require `^` will work

Comment: @pankajparkar:ya mate. its working. but just tell me one thing.... so what if my `msgpallette` needs to be at the top and `item-counter` needs to be at the bottom...... in this case how can i nest it like you told?

Comment: `require` parameter is useless for your use case (non-nested directives). You will need to create either a shared *service* or share some model object on common parent scope. This shared object on parent scope can be placed there either by controller, you can introduce third directive (i.e. back to nesting) or use `$rootScope` as the common parent (accessible as `$root` in expressions).

Comment: @dreamer element on same level can not communicate through directive, either you could create another wrapper directive for both `msgpallete` & `item-counter` which is possible do-able

Answer (score 1):

`require:'^msgpallete'`

The `require` parameter has additional functionality if you look through the docs for it.

1. someDirective : Require someDirective on same element and pass it to
   linking function
2. ?someDirective : Pass someDirective controller if available on same element to linking function. If not, pass null.
3. ^someDirective : Require someDirective on one of the parent elements and pass it to linking function.
4. ?^someDirective : Pass someDirective controller if available on one of parent elements to linking function. If not, pass null.

It has been a little while since I have done this and the directive you are requiring may need to explicitly defined a controller. Just defining and return an empty controller is enough.

```
.directive('parent', function() {
    return: {
        controller: function() {return {}}
    }
})
```

Comment: nope.that wont work.still getting the error `Controller 'msgpallete', required by directive 'itemCounter', can't be found!`

Comment: Did you also define and return a controller for 'msgpallete'?

Comment: i tried with and without the `controller` for `msgpalette`

Comment: oh, I miss read your HTML, your directives are siblings. Yeah, there is no way to require another directive in that case. One needs to be a parent of another. If you are trying to share data between then then a service would be the best thing.

Comment: @Enzey thanks for providing a great amount of detail in your answer. helped me a lot even if you didn't get the "accepted answer"